# WinJS Promise based file upload queue

Tags: javascript, queue, promise, winjs, blockingqueue

## Scenario

I need a background upload queue that sends files to a server.
The queue should send the files in sequential order as they are pushed into the queue (FIFO).

## My solution

```
var pendingFiles = [];
var filesOperation = null;

uploadNextAsync = function(file) {
  var next;
  if (!pendingFiles.length) {
    return WinJS.Promise.as();
  }
  next = pendingFiles.shift();
  fileslogger.debug("Uploading " + next);
  return fileQuery.folder.getFileAsync(next).then(function(file) {
    return Server.sendFileAsync(file).then(function() {
      return filesOk += 1;
    }, function(error) {
      filesNok += 1;
      return logger.error(error.message, error);
    }).then(function() {
      if (pendingFiles.length) {
        return uploadNextAsync(inspection);
      }
    });
  });
};

createTaskForFile = function(file) {
  if (pendingFiles.length == 0) {
    pendingFiles = [file.name]
    filesOperation = uploadNextAsync(file);
  } else {
    pendingFiles.push(file.name);
    return filesOperation.then(function() {
      return uploadNextAsync(file);
    });
  }
};
```

## Problem

It seems that sometimes if createTaskForFile is called very quickly in succession then 2 files end up being uploaded at the same time. So somewhere is a little glitch either in the `createTastForFile` function on how it uses the `fileOperation.then` construct or inside the uploadNextAsync does something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `pendingFiles` is always empty. In `createTaskForFile`, you would set it to an one-element array then, but immediately call `uploadNextAsync()` which shifts it out. I guess your script might work if you shifted the file *after* the file has been uploaded.

However, you actually don't need this array. You can just queue the action to `filesOperation`, which would be a promise representing the upload of all current files.

```
var filesOperation = WinJS.Promise.as();
function createTaskForFile(file) {
  return filesOperation = filesOperation.then(function() {
    return uploadNextAsync(file);
  });
}

function uploadAsync(next) {
  fileslogger.debug("Uploading " + next.name);
  return fileQuery.folder.getFileAsync(next.name).then(function(file) {
    return Server.sendFileAsync(file);
  }).then(function() {
    return filesOk += 1;
  }, function(error) {
    filesNok += 1;
    return logger.error(error.message, error);
  });
}
```

Comment: aha! Interesting yes. How does this work in regard of memory consumption. Are the "done" promises kept around?

And what about a break condition that cancels the update queue like a file with a specific type (.xml) that has been uploaded? Should I set the `filesOperation` to `WinJS.Promise.as()` again in that case?

Comment: The done promises are not kept around once they are resolved. Only the last one is stored in `filesOperation` (and subsequent ones overwrite this variable). You might store them however somewhere else, as `createTaskForFile` returns each of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "break". Yes, if one `uploadAsync` promise is rejected, it would cancel all queued operations (without the possibility to restart them). However, as it is written `uploadAsync` never rejects, all errors are handled (with `filesNok += 1`). To create a new (empty) queue you'd then reset `filesOperation` to `WinJS.Promise.as()`; if you wanted to resume the queue you'd need to actually handle the exception with a "wait-until-continue" promise.